# WP7 manual test of dynamic Tile

Tags: windows-phone-7, tiles, agent

I have built a dynamic Tile in my Windows Phone 7 application.
I've got my own schedule of meetings. Agent checks first available meeting, creates a proper jpeg and puts jpeg on current tile. 
When I run app for the first time, it's working fine. But I have no idea how to test changing of tile contents in time. Let's say I've got one two hour meeting. Tile is changing every half an hour, so next change of tile contents should take place sometime in between 2 and 2,5 hours. I don't want to wait such a long time.. How to test it without waiting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the frequency at which the background agent runs. The only solution to update the tile at a faster pace is to use push notifications. That is, notifications pushed by a remote server. Of course, it's only possible if the server can access the list of meetings, otherwise it's a dead end.

Comment: Ok, but as I know, background agent cannot run with higher frequency than 1 time per half an hour?

Comment: @interneo Yes, that's why the only alternative is using push notifications, that are not dependant of the background agent